# MSVC compiler bug causing error with iterators and friend functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, iterator, friend

I've been working on a small-scale test to see if I can figure out some compiler-specific larger-scale problems with a larger container. The following code works fine in GCC but causes the following error code in Visual Studio 2010 and 2013:

"Error  1   error C2675: unary '--' : 'std::iterator' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator d:\programming\workspaces\adl_test\main.cpp 127 1   adL_test_msvc"

Test code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

namespace nsp
{

template <class element_type, class element_allocator_type = std::allocator<element_type> >
class test_container
{
private:
    element_type numbers[50];
    friend class iterator;
    friend class reverse_iterator;

public:
    class reverse_iterator; //forward decl

    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, element_type>
    {
    private: 
        element_type *i;

        template <class distance_type>
        friend void advance(reverse_iterator &rit, distance_type n);
    public: 

        iterator() {}

        iterator(element_type &_i)
        {
            i = &(_i);
        }

        element_type & operator *()
        {
            return *i;
        }

        iterator & operator = (const element_type &source_i)
        {
            i = &(source_i);
            return *this;
        }

        iterator & operator = (const iterator &source)
        {
            i = source.i;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator != (const iterator rh)
        {
            return i != rh.i;
        }

        iterator & operator ++()
        {
            ++i;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator & operator --()
        {
            --i;
            return *this;
        }



        template <class distance_type>
        friend void advance(iterator &it, distance_type n)
        {
            it.i += n;
        }

        friend typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::difference_type distance(const iterator &first, const iterator &last)
        {
            return last.i - first.i;
        }


    };



    class reverse_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, element_type>
    {
    private: 
        iterator it;

    public: 

        reverse_iterator(element_type &_i)
        {
            it.i = _i;
        }

        reverse_iterator(const iterator &source)
        {
            it = source;
        }

        element_type & operator *()
        {
            return *it;
        }

        element_type & operator = (const reverse_iterator &source)
        {
            it = source.it;
            return *this;
        }

        element_type & operator = (const iterator &source)
        {
            it = source;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator != (const iterator rh)
        {
            return it != rh.it;
        }

        reverse_iterator & operator ++()
        {
            --it;
            return *this;
        }

        reverse_iterator & operator --()
        {
            ++it;
            return *this;
        }



        template <class distance_type>
        friend void advance(reverse_iterator &rit, distance_type n)
        {
            rit.it.i -= n;
        }

        friend typename std::iterator_traits<reverse_iterator>::difference_type distance(const reverse_iterator &first, const reverse_iterator &last)
        {
            return distance(last.it, first.it);
        }


    };


    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(numbers[0]);
    }


    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(numbers[50]);
    }


};


}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    nsp::test_container<int> stuff;

    int counter = 0;

    for (nsp::test_container<int>::iterator it = stuff.begin(); it != stuff.end(); ++it)
    {
        *it = counter++;
    }

    nsp::test_container<int>::iterator it = stuff.begin(), it2 = stuff.begin();

    using namespace std;

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    ++it;
    --it;
    ++it;


    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    advance(it, 2);

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    std::advance(it, 2);

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    int distance_between = distance(it2, it);

    std::cout << distance_between << std::endl;

    nsp::test_container<int>::reverse_iterator rit = it, rit2 = it2;

    --rit;
    ++rit;
    advance(rit, -2);

    distance_between = distance(rit2, rit);
    std::cout << distance_between << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously the -- operator works fine on iterator as is demonstrated in the code, but when called from reverse_iterator MSVC creates an error, despite reverse_iterator being a friend. Why?
And what is the workaround for this bug?

Don't suggest different ways of approaching the code (ie. modifying i directly instead of calling -- operator), this is a **test case**, not actual working code. It does not represent the complexity of the actual code and I won't explain to you why the actual code works in this way because I don't have time.

Comment: Does `iterator` inside `reverse_iterator` refer to the sibling class or the base class?

Comment: @immibis - Thanks, that was the issue.
Will correct and post answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to immibus, the answer has been found:
GCC believes 'iterator' within reverse_iterator refers to test_container::iterator, whereas (for some reason) MSVC 2010-2013 believes it refers to the base class.
The solution is to be more specific when specifying iterator within reverse_iterator - using "typename test_container::iterator" instead of "iterator".

Corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

namespace nsp
{

template <class element_type, class element_allocator_type = std::allocator<element_type> >
class test_container
{
private:
    element_type numbers[50];
    friend class iterator;
    friend class reverse_iterator;

public:
    class reverse_iterator; //forward decl

    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, element_type>
    {
    private: 
        element_type *i;

        template <class distance_type>
        friend void advance(reverse_iterator &rit, distance_type n);
    public: 

        iterator() {}

        iterator(element_type &_i)
        {
            i = &(_i);
        }

        element_type & operator *()
        {
            return *i;
        }

        iterator & operator = (const element_type &source_i)
        {
            i = &(source_i);
            return *this;
        }

        iterator & operator = (const iterator &source)
        {
            i = source.i;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator != (const iterator rh)
        {
            return i != rh.i;
        }

        iterator & operator ++()
        {
            ++i;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator & operator --()
        {
            --i;
            return *this;
        }



        template <class distance_type>
        friend void advance(iterator &it, distance_type n)
        {
            it.i += n;
        }

        friend typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::difference_type distance(const iterator &first, const iterator &last)
        {
            return last.i - first.i;
        }


    };



    class reverse_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, element_type>
    {
    private: 
        typename test_container::iterator it;

    public: 

        reverse_iterator(element_type &_i)
        {
            it.i = _i;
        }

        reverse_iterator(const typename test_container::iterator &source)
        {
            it = source;
        }

        element_type & operator *()
        {
            return *it;
        }

        element_type & operator = (const reverse_iterator &source)
        {
            it = source.it;
            return *this;
        }

        element_type & operator = (const typename test_container::iterator &source)
        {
            it = source;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator != (const typename test_container::iterator rh)
        {
            return it != rh.it;
        }

        reverse_iterator & operator ++()
        {
            --it;
            return *this;
        }

        reverse_iterator & operator --()
        {
            ++it;
            return *this;
        }



        template <class distance_type>
        friend void advance(reverse_iterator &rit, distance_type n)
        {
            rit.it.i -= n;
        }

        friend typename std::iterator_traits<reverse_iterator>::difference_type distance(const reverse_iterator &first, const reverse_iterator &last)
        {
            return distance(last.it, first.it);
        }


    };


    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(numbers[0]);
    }


    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(numbers[50]);
    }


};


}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    nsp::test_container<int> stuff;

    int counter = 0;

    for (nsp::test_container<int>::iterator it = stuff.begin(); it != stuff.end(); ++it)
    {
        *it = counter++;
    }

    nsp::test_container<int>::iterator it = stuff.begin(), it2 = stuff.begin();

    using namespace std;

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    ++it;
    --it;
    ++it;

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    advance(it, 2);

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    std::advance(it, 2);

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    int distance_between = distance(it2, it);

    std::cout << distance_between << std::endl;

    nsp::test_container<int>::reverse_iterator rit = it, rit2 = it2;

    --rit;
    ++rit;
    advance(rit, -2);

    distance_between = distance(rit2, rit);
    std::cout << distance_between << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```